# Paint function will not iterate more than 3 times Java

Tags: java, swing

So every time I run the program and type 1 into the system, it will only allow me to move the oval once,then the program will print debug 2 more times without moving the oval. Why?

```
    import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

/**
 *
 * @author Admin
 */
public class TestingGame extends JFrame{
    public Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static int x = 0;
    public static int y = 0;
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestingGame myFrame = new TestingGame();
        myFrame.setSize(1000,1000);
        myFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        myFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(myFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        myFrame.setVisible(true);


    }
    public void paint(Graphics g){
        update(g);
    }    
    public void update(Graphics g){
        Graphics2D ga = (Graphics2D)g;
        ga.drawOval(x, y, 50, 50);
        int input = scan.nextInt();
        if(input == 1){
            System.out.println("Debug");
            x = x + 100;
            y = y + 100;
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Don't extend from `JFrame`, don't override `paint` (generally but especially) of top level containers like `JFrame`, you will end up painting in places you don't want to pant (like under the borders).  Don't do anything that would block the paint process, like using `scan.nextInt()`! This will cause your UI to "freeze"

Comment: Have a look at [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html), [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) and [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details

Comment: Also, don't override the update(...) method. That is something you would do when using AWT, NOT Swing.